# Truncar tabelas com cascade

Tags: sql, oracle

Tenho uma tabela hotel e a tabela reserva.

Na tabela reserva tenho a chave primária da tabela hotel como chave estrangeira.

Não consigo truncar porque há relações entre chaves. Como posso fazer?

Já fiz:

```
truncate table hospede on delete cascade;
```

Mas não consigo.

Só lembrando que as fk estão com `on delete cascade`. E que uso a versão 11g express edition.

Answer (score 2):

O `on delete cascade` só deve ser usado em algumas instruções **DDL** (*data definition language*), e não em instruções **DML** (*data manipulation language*). Ou seja, é para usar apenas onde há alteração na estrutura das tabelas, e não nos dados. Porém no seu caso, você só quer apagar os dados sem alterar a estrutura das tabelas.

Assim sendo, eu faria o seguinte:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE hospede;
TRUNCATE TABLE reserva;
TRUNCATE TABLE hotel;
```

A ordem das instruções é importante.

Comment: Se isso não funcionar, edite a pergunta fornecendo nomes de colunas e como são definidos os relacionamentos.

Comment: não testei porque eu apagei as constraints e trunquei a tabela. Se estivesse uma maneira de forçar o truncate sem tanta volta, seria ideal.

Comment: As constraints existem para garantir a integridade das tabelas , não as usando pode-se fazer o que quiser mas com risco. Fora isto muitas vezes é uma simples questão de ordem em que os trucates ou deletes são feitos como disse o @Victor Stafusa.